# Error in MySQL trigger after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am creating trigger for after insert but I am getting error.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ParticleTableInsert 
AFTER INSERT
 ON Particle  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Particles_Log(Message) VALUES ('Pace_Particles_Log');
 END;
 DELIMITER ;
```

I am new to mysql, sonot understanding what is wrong with my query. Please help.

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: I think you should provide a space between Particles_Log and (Message) as the query considers Particles_Log(Message) to be a table name

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ParticleTableInsert 
AFTER INSERT
 ON Particle  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Particles_Log(Message) VALUES ('Pace_Particles_Log');
 END//
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: This should work. But you should explain, what you have changed. BTW: For a single-statement trigger you don't need `BEGIN` and `END`. And without them you don't need to change the delimiter.